# Crosstab using data from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I have 2 tables measurement_timestamps and sensor_double_precision of the following form:

```
id    start_time    stop_time
 1    2020-02-22    2020-02-24
 2    2020-02-25    2020-02-27
```

and

```
id    sensor_name    value_cal    timestamp
 1    start_freq            15    2020-02-23
 2    stop_freq             18    2020-02-23
 3    start_freq            15    2020-02-26
 4    stop_freq             18    2020-02-26
```

I want a VIEW that looks at measurement timestamps and for each start_time - stop_time pair, pivots (transposes?) the sensor_name column such that start_freq and stop_freq become there own columns with the respective value_cal as the rows.

So I basically want the VIEW to looks like this:

```
id    start_freq    stop_freq    timestamp
 1            15           18    2020-02-23
 2            15           18    2020-02-26
```

Notice how the timestamp associated with id 1 in the VIEW is in between the start_time and stop_time for id 1 in the measurement_timestamps table.

What is a reasonable way of doing this? I do not want to create a VIEW for each individual sensor_name because I have many more sensors than this and it just doesn't seem very robust. The following is an approach that I have been recommended but it does not seem to work because I am probably doing something wrong.

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab('with current_data as (
        select distinct on (mt.id)
                mt.id, sdp.sensor_name, sdp.value_cal
            from measurement_timestamps mt, sensor_double_precision sdp
            order by mt.id desc
    ),
    ids as (
        select distinct id from current_data
    ),
    sensor_names as (
        select distinct sensor_name from current_data
    )
    select ids.id, sensor_names.sensor_name, current_data.value_cal
    from ids cross join sensor_names
    left join current_data on (ids.id=current_data.id and sensor_names.sensor_name=current_data.sensor_name)
    order by ids.id,sensor_names.sensor_name') final_data (id integer, start_freq double precision,
                                                        stop_freq double precision, timestamp timestamp)
```

Sidenote - start_freq and stop_freq don't seem like sensor names but I am working with a table that follows a standardized form because of which we are calling it sensor_name. There are also other sensors that I am not worried about for this task.

EDIT - result from the query that was suggested below:

```
id.  start_freq       stop_freq.             timestamp
18      15             null         "2020-07-09 20:03:38.937195+00"
19     null             18.         "2020-07-09 20:03:39.051836+00"
20     null            null          "2020-07-09 20:03:39.171837+00"
21     null            null         "2020-07-09 20:03:39.287994+00"
22     null            null         "2020-07-09 20:03:39.287994+00"
23     15              null         "2020-07-09 20:03:39.287994+00"
24     null            18           "2020-07-09 20:03:39.287994+00"
```

EDIT2 - The data I have attached in the problem is sample data to make the problem easier to talk about. The structure and everything are similar to the real data set.

Comment: If you only have two sensor names then use a `case` expression. You mentioned something about not wanting multiple views so perhaps this isn't what the actual data looks like?

Comment: This is basically what the data looks like. There are other sensor_names but I don't really care about them so I left them out. I have used ``CASE`` statements but it leaves ``NULL`` values between datapoints.

Comment: What if more than two rows in the second table match the first table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
ideally ignore them but, I can always select whatever I need so I am willing to compromise is I have to pivot every sensor_name over as a column. There indeed are sensors that will fall under what you just described

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve it. (conditionally only one set of start and stop event with in time range of `measurement_timestamps`  )

1. using Normal `aggregation` and `filter`

```
select 
m.id, 
min(s.value_cal) filter (where sensor_name='start_freq'),
min(s.value_cal) filter (where sensor_name='stop_freq'),
min(s.timestamp) filter (where sensor_name='stop_freq')
from measurement_timestamps m 
inner join sensor_double_precision s on s.timestamp between m.start_time and m.stop_time
group by m.id
```

**Note:** you have not specified which date you want so i have taken `stop_freq timestamp`. You can change what you want.

2. Using `Crosstab` (Your Way)

```
select * from crosstab('select 
m.id, 
s.timestamp,
s.sensor_name,
s.value_cal
from measurement_timestamps m 
inner join sensor_double_precision s on s.timestamp between m.start_time and m.stop_time',
'select ''start_freq'' union select ''stop_freq'' ') as (id int, timestamp date, start_freq varchar, stop_freq varchar)
```

**Note:** Above will work correctly only when `start_freq timestamp` and `stop_freq timestamp` is same

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fc6628409db4c1f4b4835aef0b5265c5)

Comment: I ran the query you suggested. Although it didn't give me any error, it didn't work either. It kept trying to load and seemed to get stuck. I even added LIMIT 10 at the end but that didn't help either.

Comment: you can check the fiddle. But what is the error or difference

Comment: I also don't know how to get the Crosstab way working either. May I ask how what you suggested is different from using ```case``` statements as suggested by the other answer?

Comment: Only one difference if start and stop date is different then Mine will work but other wont work.

Comment: @Parashar Can you tell what is exactly not working. If you have a huge data then put where clause with your start_time and stop_time instead of limit

Comment: Thanks for the link you attached. I didn't know there was service like this! Unfortunately, the query is taking just as long to execute in the real DB. I am not sure why:(

Comment: I really can't tell what is going wrong because its taking forever to load. Also the timestamps of start_time and stop_time are slightly different. The hours/minutes are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220118/discussion-between-akhilesh-mishra-and-parashar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this shouldn't work. Your comment about "null values between datapoints" doesn't make sense to me though.

```
select
    m.id,
    min(case when m.sensor_name = 'start_freq' then m.value_cal end) as start_freq,
    min(case when m.sensor_name = 'stop_freq'  then m.value_cal end) as stop_freq, 
    s.timestamp
from measurement_timestamps m inner join sensor_double_precision s
    on s.timestamp between m.start_time and m.stop_time
group by m.id, s.timestamp
```

Comment: I cant really show you the error because I can't upload a picture here but I am getting ```null``` values in between datapoints. By this I mean when start_freq is say 15, the corresponding stop_freq should be 18 but this query returns ```null```. when stop freq is 18, start_freq is ```null```

Comment: I just edited the question and posted the result of your query.

Comment: Your data clearly doesn't match what you specified in the question.

Comment: umm it does match. the extra nulls at the bottom are from the 'other sensor_names' that I dont really care about. I just updated the result of your query with a few more rows. I just added what I saw at the bottom. the 3 rows in the middle of just ```null``` values are from the sensors I dont care about